# SOA Installation Failuer

Tags: soa

[image]

We are getting below error while installing SOA , can anyone help on this, to overcome this error

Answer (score 0):

The version of SOA you are installing is not compatible and certified on the host machine. Please read Oracle certification matrix before choosing SOA version,OS flavor and version